# Typesafe-Config jvm options cannot be received in flink

Tags: apache-flink, typesafe-config

There is a Flink project using typesafe config, when I tried to run the project in **a standalone cluster** with the command `flink run xxxx.jar -Dconfig=XXXX -Dus=XXXX...`, I found that the JVM options(here is *config* and *us*) cannot be recognized correctly. Usually, it should **replace** the value of the corresponding key in `application.conf` withe value `XXXX`.

Comment: How do you access configuration? Remember that flink works in a distributed manner. Therefore if you want to use typesafe, you can read it and store to some serializable object before submitting to cluster.

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz Hey, I have a `application.conf`, the programe can read data from it, it is already been serialized, my problem is there are some data(for example, password), I dont write it directly in the file, so I want to pass it by a jvm option with the help of `-D`, but obviously, Flink cannot receive it in a standalone cluster

Comment: I understand how it works, but as far as I know typesafe config it reads the file whenever you invoke `Config.load`. If you do it on TaskManager e.g. in `MapFunction` it does no longer has access to System properties of the client.

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz hey, Dawid, I think I found an instresting point, right now, Flink supports dynamical JVM parameters only on a YARN cluster with the options `-yD <arg> `, not on a standalone cluster.

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz I think, for the access to system properties in TaskManager, which will not be involved, because it dosen't receive these properties

Answer (score 0):

Use

`ParameterTool parameter = ParameterTool.fromSystemProperties();`

to access your `config` and `us` parameters.

Getting your configuration values into the ParameterTool:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/best_practices.html#getting-your-configuration-values-into-the-parametertool

Comment: hey, Alex, thank you for your answer, but what I want is not code. In lightbend/config, uesers can override the config with Java system properties, which means I don't need to code to get the those parameters, no ?